# Sklearn: not receiving transformer parameters while trying to crossvalidate pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, python-3.8

I am trying to use the cross_validate function on a pipeline. The pipeline works correctly if I train it normally with fit but I am getting an error when i use the cross_validate. Basically, the parameters I pass to the transformer on the pipeline are NoneType when I use the cross_validate function. Why is this the case and how could I fix it? I tried to do a minimum example here

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

import pandas as pd

class Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, model, mtype, mname, num_labels: int):
        self._model = model
        self._inst_model = None
        self._num_labels = num_labels
        self._type = mtype
        self._name =mname
        
        
    def fit(self, train_input, y=None):
        self._create_model()
        self._train_model(train_input)
        return self
    
    def transform(self, eval_df, y=None):
        result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = self._inst_model.eval_model(eval_df=eval_df)
        return model_outputs
    
    def _create_model(self):
        self._inst_model = self._model(self._type, self._name, args={"output_dir": 'min_ex'},
                                  num_labels=self._num_labels)
        
    def _train_model(self, train_input):
        train_df, eval_df = train_test_split(train_input, test_size=0.20)
        return self._inst_model.train_model(train_df, eval_df=eval_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    categories = ['sci.med', 'sci.space']
    X_t, y_t = fetch_20newsgroups(random_state=1,
                                      subset='train',
                                      categories=categories,
                                      remove=('footers', 'quotes'),
                                      return_X_y=True)
    X = pd.DataFrame({
            'text': X_t,
            'labels': y_t,
    })
    y = y_t
    transformer_grid = {
    "model": ClassificationModel, 
    "num_labels": 14,
    "mtype": "electra",
    "mname": "german-nlp-group/electra-base-german-uncased"
    }
    
    classifier_grid = {
    'n_estimators' : 100,
    'random_state': 42
    }
    
    pipe = Pipeline([ 
    ('feats', FeatureUnion([
        ('transformer', Pipeline([
            ('transformer', Transformer(**transformer_grid)),
        ])),
    ])),    
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(**classifier_grid))
    ])
#     pipe.fit(X, y)
    cv_results = cross_validate(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=1)
```

And the error I am getting is this

```
2021-03-04 16:05:54.861544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:209: FutureWarning: From version 0.24, get_params will raise an AttributeError if a parameter cannot be retrieved as an instance attribute. Previously it would return None.
  warnings.warn('From version 0.24, get_params will raise an '
/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:548: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 330, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 292, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 352, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 953, in fit_transform
    results = self._parallel_func(X, y, fit_params, _fit_transform_one)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 978, in _parallel_func
    return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(func)(
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1029, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 847, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 765, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 572, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 252, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 252, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 376, in fit_transform
    return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 693, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "min_ex.py", line 23, in fit
    self._create_model()
  File "min_ex.py", line 32, in _create_model
    self._inst_model = self._model(self._type, self._name, args={"output_dir": 'min_ex'},
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

  warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
```

Edit:

I changed to use another variable for when the model is instantiated, still the same issue. Took out print statements for easier reading. The only thing missing for the code to run is the loading of data. It still gives me same error only when crossvalidate

Edit 2:

Created a minimal reproducible example by adding a synthetic dataset

Comment: Hi, this isn’t an [mre]; you’ll get better answers if you convert it to one. I can only speculate that the _load_model method returns None, which has caused your problem. (But you realize you’re using self._model to represent two different things?)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Hi, oh I forgot to take out the load_model method, it doesn't affect anything here so it shouldn't be the problem. I edited it out. The thing is that if I use the fit method on the pipeline it works completely fine. The problem is with cross_validate.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Hi, now it should work as a minimal reproducible example with a synthetic dataset